# How to create a matrix from a table with three text columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have created a view out of some tables which consist data regarding authorisation info for some users. An example:

```
Role         Page         Right

Admin        Home         RW
Manager      Home         RW
Viewer       Home         R
Admin        Overview     RW
Manager      Overview     R
Viewer       Overview     R
Admin        Settings     RW
```

My goal is to create a new view like a matrix, which shows the following:

```
Page         Admin     Manager   Viewer

Home          RW         RW        R
Overview      RW         R         R
Settings      RW
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this in SSMS, keeping in mind that more roles could be added in the future and I don't have to update my code every time a role is created?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution is to use a dynamic pivot, but you can't use dynamic SQL in a view. I think you might be able to do this with some complex XML function, maybe someone can figure that out.

Comment: You definitely will not be able to do this in a view as this will require dynamic sql. Something in your requirements will have to change here as you can't use dynamic sql in a view. Maybe you can use a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Sean is right, Views are simply a pre-compiled `SELECT` statement; they can't have things like `DECLARE`, or `EXEC` in them, or even multiple single `SELECT`s. A function is off the cards too, as you can't use `EXEC` in those either; which leaves you with only one type of object; an SP.

Comment: So if I choose to ditch the dynamic part of the requirement, it is possible?

Comment: The dynamic element will pick up your new roles without intervention

Comment: *"So if I choose to ditch the dynamic part of the requirement, it is possible?"* Yes, but that conflicts with your with the requirement *"Is there a way I can accomplish this in SSMS, keeping in mind that more roles could be added in the future and I don't have to update my code every time a role is created"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use PIVOT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t
PIVOT (MAX([RIGHT]) FOR [ROLE] IN ([Admin], [Manager], [Viewer])) AS pvt
```

If you have a changing Role column you may use code like this:

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @ColumnNames = STUFF(
           (
               SELECT DISTINCT ',['  + [ROLE]+ ']'
               FROM  trtr
               ORDER BY 1 
                      FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '') 

DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 'SELECT * 
FROM trtr AS t
PIVOT (MAX([RIGHT]) FOR [ROLE] IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')) AS pvt'          
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

However you wouldn't be able to use it as a view. You will have to create a procedure

Comment: this solution would work, but the script would need to be ammended every time a new role is added, not sure if this is viable for the OP

Comment: Edited the solution

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic pivot solution already posted is a good way to go with this sort of thing. I personally find the syntax for PIVOT to be obtuse and difficult to keep straight. I prefer to use conditional aggregation as the syntax is simpler for me. The performance is about the same but requires a bit less coding as well. Here is a full working example of how you might implement this using a different approach.

First the table setup:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    Role varchar(10)
    , Page varchar(10)
    , [Right] varchar(10)
)

insert #Something values
('Admin', 'Home', 'RW')
, ('Manager', 'Home', 'RW')
, ('Viewer', 'Home', 'R')
, ('Admin', 'Overview', 'RW')
, ('Manager', 'Overview', 'R')
, ('Viewer', 'Overview', 'R')
, ('Admin', 'Settings', 'RW')
```

The actual code needed here is very minimal as we are using the data to build dynamic sql for us.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + ', Max(Case when Role = ''' + Role + ''' then [Right] end) as ' + QuoteName(Role)
from #Something
group by Role

set @SQL = N'select Page ' + @SQL + ' from #Something group by Page order by Page'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```